# Rake Aborted when pushing to Heroku - Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @rb_sysopen - /tmp/build/config/application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am attempting to push to Heroku and am getting the following error:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/build_0ea6e71e6fa31065be1c41a3cb6aaacb/config/application.yml
```

Running `bundle exec rake -P` works without any errors.

application.yml is part of my .gitignore, so I'm confused why the error message has to do with this file and why it's preventing me from pushing to Heroku.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a silly mistake but posting here in case it's useful to anyone else - I was pushing the wrong branch to heroku.  Once I corrected the branch name, it worked perfectly.